# how to know the exact time thread requires to finish

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, countdownlatch

I have two threads t1 and t2. Both of them make some calculations and i am tryin to block the main thread till t1 and t2 finish. I used .awaitTermination() as seen below, but the problem is, despit it is an if-statement, the .awaitTermination() goes in an infinite loop.

please help me to find wyh that is happening. and should i specify an amount of time without knowing the exact time the t1 and t2 require to finish?

```
 executor.execute(new RunnableClass(bgr,3))
 executor.execute(new RunnableClass(bgr,7))
 executor.shutdown();

if (executor.awaitTermination(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
    print("terminated")
}
```

Comment: This is not a problem of the 'exact time' but of your use of threads.

Comment: @Tichodroma please let me know how to set the time correctly ro how to use .awaitTermination()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use Java 8, you can use `CompletableFuture<T>` instead. They define some useful methods like join to wait for their execution and chaining them together. Your example would look like this:

```
final CompletableFuture<Void> future1 = CompletableFuture.runAsync(new RunnableClass(bgr, 3), executor);
final CompletableFuture<Void> future2 = CompletableFuture.runAsync(new RunnableClass(bgr, 7), executor);
CompletableFuture.allOf(future1, future2).join(); // blocks until both finished
executor.shutdown();
```

A great introduction can be found [here](http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2013/05/java-8-definitive-guide-to.html).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the time that you pass to `awaitTermination` is an approximate value and it should always be MORE than your worst-case cumulative times taken to complete all your tasks. If it's a webservice call or a DB call that you're making in those runnables, then it's not easy not speculate some fixed time for them as it might vary based on your site's traffic. So instead of just assuming that it will always complete in some definite time, you just need to wait for all those runnables to complete before you start making use of those results.

If you cannot use `CompletableFuture` from Java8 and if you need to wait till all your runnables submited to the pool are executed, then you can use `invokeAll` on `ExecutorService` like below.

`invokeAll` will block the main thread until all the submitted callables are executed.

```
// removing try-catch blocks for brevity
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
List<Callable<Integer>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
tasks.add(new Callable<Integer>(){
     public Integer call(){
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                System.out.println("thread1 coming out of sleep");
                return 1;
     }
});

tasks.add(new Callable<Integer>(){
    public Integer call(){
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            System.out.println("thread2 coming out of sleep");
            return 2;
    }
});

List<Future<Integer>> futures = service.invokeAll(tasks);
System.out.println("back in main");

service.shutdown();
service.awaitTermination(20,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

**Output :**

```
thread1 coming out of sleep
thread2 coming out of sleep
back in main
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the `ExecutorCompletionService`. It is created on top of the executor service. Its `take()` method returns the future for the task that completes next and waits if no completed task is available yet. To wait for all submitted tasks to complete, you can call this method as many times as the number of tasks.

```
ExecutorCompletionService ecs = new ExecutorCompletionService(executorService);
for (int index = 0 ; index < numberOfTasks ; index++) {
    ecs.take(); 
}
```

This is available in Java 6, 7, & 8; might be there in previous version too. More details [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html)